# Java audio playing error

Tags: java, audio, applet

I am java newbie.

I was reading a tutorial book, and tried almost all code given as examples, and they all worked perfectly. But, when I tried this audio playing tutorial, even though I understood most of it, I still can't make it play. It gives me error, saying

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at MouseClicker.main(MouseClicker.java:9)`

Here is the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class MouseClicker extends Jframe{
    AudioClip click;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MouseClicker();
    }

    public MouseClicker(){
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setTitle("Mouse Clicker");
        this.addMouseListener(new Clicker());

        URL urlClick = MouseClicker.class.getResource("hello.wav");
        click = Applet.newAudioClip(urlClick);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    private class Clicker extends MouseAdapter
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        click.play();
    }

}
```

---

[image]

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: @Doorknob Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at MouseClicker.main(MouseClicker.java:9)

Comment: That's not a compile error. What is the error you get when you compile the program, not run it?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MouseClicker extends Jframe{
```

It's a `JFrame`, not a `Jframe`. (capital F)

Remember, Java is case sensitive!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it gave me again `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at MouseClicker.main(MouseClicker.java:9)`

Comment: @bluethief Did you recompile it?

Comment: Well, this is my first day learning JAVA, so I am just running it from eclipse. using the run arrow

Comment: @bluethief Do you not see the red underlines on the **specific lines** that there are errors on? Isn't that pretty clear?

Comment: Sorry. first day mistakes. What a hot mess :). But still, I fixed everything, and still get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(AppletAudioClip.java:65)
 at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Applet.java:311)
 at MouseClicker.<init>(MouseClicker.java:19)
 at MouseClicker.main(MouseClicker.java:10)`

Comment: @bluethief Well, do you have an audio file called `hello.wav`? You don't seem to.

Comment: I have that certainly:) Although, it is in the `src` folder. The tutorial didn't specify that, so I assumed that would be the place for it

Comment: @bluethief The file should be in the project folder.

Comment: I have included a picture of my directory in the question, and I have copy pasted, `hello.wav` in every folder, sadly there is not folder called `project` as you can see. the project is the unreadable file

Comment: this `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(AppletAudioClip.java:65)
 at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Applet.java:311)
 at MouseClicker.<init>(MouseClicker.java:19)
 at MouseClicker.main(MouseClicker.java:10)
`

Comment: also `Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error, insert "ClassBody" to complete ClassDeclaration HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/src line 24 Java Problem`

Comment: and `Description Resource Path Location Type
The public type MouseClicker must be defined in its own file HelloWorld.java /HelloWorld/src line 7 Java Problem
` sorry about this, and thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an opening brace in the definition of the `Clicker` class

```
private class Clicker extends MouseAdapter {
                                           ^
```

A Java `IDE` can highlight these syntax errors.

Also ensure that the audio file `hello.wav` is located in the same location as `MouseClicker.class`  (the `bin` folder in this case) so that it can be read as a resource.

Comment: it's like where is wally :P